# When to move from a high performance machine to a cluster in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been teaching myself Spark and Scala for the last month and have explored with local mode and clusters ranging from 5 - 20 on EC2. It feels like I would be better off without a cluster unless I become CPU or memory bound. Is this intuition correct?

Answer (score 0):

From what i have seen so far i think that without cluster you will not be able to perform operationgs on very big data since memory and CPU will come as bottleneck. From learning prospective i think that single machine is good. Although one will not be able to gain experience of working on cluster by using single machine.

Since you have work on machines ranging form 5-20 on EC2 i think that there is no harm in moving to single machine. Logic will always remain same either working on cluster or single machine. Only environment changes(my thinking).